# How to validate fields without form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Following is my code

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" onclick="OpenDialog()" value="Add Record" />      
<div id="AddBox" style="display: none">
<label>Install</label>
<input type="text" id="Install" />
<label>Payout</label>
<input type="text" id="Payout" />
<label>Start Date</label>   
<input type="text" id="reqStartDate" value="@ViewBag.StartDate" name="reqStartDate" readonly="true" />
<label>End Date</label>
<input type="text" id="reqEndDate" value="" name="reqEndDate" readonly="true" />            
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenDialog() {
        $('#AddBox').dialog({
        title: 'New Client',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            show: {
    effect: "slide",
    duration: 800
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "fold",
    duration: 800
  },
   buttons: {
        "Add":function onsave() {
        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("BountyMatrix", "Marketing")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        clientkey: $('#reqClientID').val(),
        install: $('#Install').val(),
        payout: $('#Payout').val(),
        StartDate: $('#reqStartDate').val(),
        EndDate: $('#reqEndDate').val()
        },

        success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
        $('#AddBox').dialog('close');
        location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
        alert('Try Again :(');
        }
        });      
        }
        },
        height: 370,
        width: 440,
        modal: false
        });

        var name = $('#Name').val();
        var address = $('#Address').val();
        $('#Dialog-Name').val(name);
        $('#Dialog-Address').val(address);
        $('#AddBox').dialog('open');
    }
    </script>
```

I have a button that opens a dialog box,it contains textboxes without form tag,button in dialog box post a form.I just wanted to add validation to textboxes that if these boxes are empty the form should not be submitted.How should i do it using jquery validation ?

Comment: You cannot use the jQuery Validate plugin without form tags, although it's somewhat unclear if this question is about the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check for the value in the boxes on submit the form . i.e. on clicking the submit button. suppose your submit button has the id of "submit_button" then:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(){ 
  if ($("#text_field1").val() == "")
    alert('please fill the required field')
  else if ($("#text_field2").val() == "")
    alert('please fill the required field')
  else
    return true;
});
```

i guess you are looking for something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/FJqVV/

Answer (score 0):

you can validate like this.

```
if($("#Install").val()=='')
     return false;
```

use this in OpenDialog() function, for each textbox you want to validate write else if.